# Drools V6 - Remove old KieModules with KieScanner

Tags: drools, kie

KieRepository holds the old versions of KieModule forever ([Bug DROOLS-381](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-381)).The fix for this bug is that old version can be explicity removed with a call `KieRepository.removeKieModule(ReleaseId oldVersionReleaseId)`.

When there is a KieScanner registered to scan for new versions of releaseId, does that implicitly call `kieRepo.removeKieModule(oldVersion)`?

If not, is there any events published by KieScanner that releaseId has been upgraded, so that we can explicitly call `kieRepo.removeKieModule`

Comment: Probably a better question for the Drools user group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/drools-usage

Comment: Thank you @Steve , I shall post the question in the group as well.

Comment: for reference posted the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640529/drools-6-3-0-old-zipkiemodules-remain-in-the-heap-after-upgrading-executing-sc