# Drools 6.3.0: Old ZiPKieModules remain in the heap after upgrading (executing scanNow in kiescanner JMX bean)

Tags: java, heap-memory, drools, wildfly-10, kie

We are using **drools 6.3.0** and implemented our **kiemodule** as a deployable maven artifact (kjar). Our application uses this kiemodule and runs in Wildfly-10.

In production, newer version of the kiemodule are automatically  detected and loaded in the application by a kieScanner that runs at regular intervals.

If the scanner sees a new version of the kiemodule it will load it on-the-fly and at runtime.

This is very cool functionality, but recently we discovered that every time a new ZipKieModule is loaded, **the old ZipKieModule remains on the heap and is not GC'ed!**

That means if we do not restart the servers AND deploy a lot of new KieModules we are susceptible to out-of-memory exceptions since each kiemodule-upgrade consumes appr. 150mb on the heap.

Can anybody point me in the right direction how to analzye why these ZipKieModukles are not gc'ed?

I attached a screenshot to this post that shows the report the Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT, http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php) created that clearly indicates that 6 instances of the ZipKieModule are clogging the heap and are suspects for a memory leak:

[image]

Hope anybody can help :)